# How to SFTP send files created 1 minute ago, Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, sftp

How can I send files from a Linux machine to an sftp server that were created 1 minute ago?

I have tried using find, but I’m not sure how to pipe it through to sftp?

I have tried something like below

```
find | sftp {user}@{host}:{remote_dir} <<< $'put {local_file_path}'
```

But I don’t know how to pipe the files created one minute ago into the sftp command.

I cannot install additional packages as the Linux machine is not connected to the internet.

Comment: If you want to transfer files as they're created, a cron job that looks at timestamps is not a particularly reliably way to do it. I'd strongly suggest using `incron` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have strange file names:

```
$ find -mmin -10 | sed 's/^/put /' | sftp -b - sorin@192.168.0.14
sftp> put ./16/test00116.gz
sftp> put ./20200113.gz
sftp> put ./log20200128.gz
```

- `-b -` - read a batch file from stdin
- `sed 's/^/put /'` - prefix each file with the put command.

A bit more robust, removing the uploaded file before trying to put the new one, and making sure sftp doesn't exit on error:

```
$ find -mmin -10 -exec basename -- "{}" \; -print | sed '1~2s/^/-rm /;0~2s/^/-put /' |  sftp -b - sorin@192.168.0.14
sftp> -rm exisingfile20200102.gz
sftp> -put ./2/existingfile20200102.gz
sftp> -rm newfile20200121.gz
Couldn't delete file: No such file or directory
sftp> -put ./21/newfile20200121.gz
```

Comment: Can this script be run with a cron job? I was hoping I could run it minutely with cron and send files created in the last minute with a set extension with cron.

Comment: I don't see why not, but your find will need to have full search path, an you might consider using full paths for all the utilities. Also, you might consider redirecting the output of sftp into a log file.

Comment: one caveat: if the destination exists and is bigger than the source the file will not be overwritten. Also, sftp will exit if any of the files give an error;